# How to keep org-mode links from stretching over text in unspaced languages?

Tags: emacs, language, latex, org-mode

In Japanese and other languages, there are no spaces in a paragraph. Org-mode interprets this as a continuation of a link description, which messes up the semantics and formatting.

Example:

```
[[link][いろはに]]ほへと、
```

The output (if including the proper `\usepackage{CJK}` in the header for LaTeX), will have a link that bleeds to the right until a punctuation mark is found.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to change the LaTeX exporter to pLaTeX, which is formulated for Japanese. However, this breaks English export. Furthermore, it's difficult to unravel cosmetically, since the entire passage is shown as a link in Emacs:

[image]

edit: XeLaTeX can handle this and other mixed Unicode issues. You can change this in the org PDF Export Process customization.